# Excel VBA - Insert Row & Insert Column Macros

Tags: vba, excel

I have a "Task Tracker" workbook that uses columns A:J to display and calculate task information (A:E are for user-entered data, F:J contain formulas that use the information in C:E and perform calculations.  F:J are hidden cells in the user view.)  The remainder of the columns display a heat map of where the tasks fall on a timeline, and whether or not they are running on time, are behind, or are complete.

There are two buttons for users to use:  one to insert a new row, and one to insert a new column.  The InsertRow() macro inserts a row into the list, then copies the formulas down from the above row.  The InsertColumn() macro locates the last used column in the worksheet and copies everything over from the column to the left of it.

Originally, I had a macro for InsertRow using Range that copied from Column F (where the formulas start) to Column XFD.  However, once I created the InsertColumn macro I realized that I cannot do InsertRow like that because InsertColumn needs to locate the last data-containing column in the worksheet and add a new one to the right...and if InsertRow gets run first, InsertColumn won't work because the value for lastColumn comes back as the index of column XFD.

**What I am looking for help with:**
I need to locate the lastColumn value in my InsertRow macro, then use that value as part of the Range when the program executes the Copy/Paste portion of the code.  I think that the problem I'm having has to do with the fact that the code I'm using to find the last column returns the index, and the Range function needs the name of the column.

Here is what I have for both macros:

```
Sub InsertTaskRow()

' InsertTaskRow Macro
'
' This macro inserts a new row below whatever role the user currently has selected, then
' copies the formulas and formatting from above down to the new row

    Dim lastColumn As Long
    Dim currrentRow As Long
    Dim newRow As Long

    lastColumn = ActiveSheet.Range("A1").SpecialCells(xlCellTypeLastCell).Column

    currentRow = ActiveCell.Row
    newRow = currentRow + 1
    ActiveCell.Offset(1).EntireRow.Insert Shift:=xlDown

    Range("F" & currentRow & ":" & lastColumn & currentRow).Copy Destination:=Range("F" & newRow & ":" & currentRow & newRow)

End Sub


Sub InsertColumn()

' InsertColumn Macro
'
' This macro copies the formulas and formatting from the last data-containing column
' in the worksheet, and pastes it into the next column to the right.

    Dim lastColumn As Long

    lastColumn = ActiveSheet.Range("A1").SpecialCells(xlCellTypeLastCell).Column

    MsgBox lastColumn

    Columns(lastColumn).Copy Destination:=Columns(lastColumn + 1)

End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try changing your `lastColumn` occurances to the following:

```
lastColumn = ActiveSheet.Range("A1").End(xlToRight).Column
```

This will stretch your range to all used cells. I tried using the clCellTypeLastCell, but it was pulling further than necessary for no apparent reason; even after deleting the entire columns it claimed were applicable. Just an FYI, there is no issue with using indexes or column names when utilizing `Range()` - even interchangibly, they are both fully qualified.

Comment: Thank you.  I tried using that code to locate the last column, but rather than find the last column *used* it returns the last column in the worksheet.

Comment: It is because the data in row 1 is empty : xlToRight needs will go to the first empty cell when on data, or on the first data when empty.